# HTML Bootstrap Well issue when using html template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to import a HTML template into my index.html. The template will be placed into the wrapper div however, the wrapper div will no longer be inside of the "well" which was created in the parent div.

I need to have the template imported and be inside of the "well" instead of outside.

Thanks for the help.

index.html:

```
<div class="row">
            <div id="parent" class=" well col-m-12">

                <h4>Experiment parameters</h4>
                <p>Full of input boxes which update both views above</p>

                <div id="wrapper" class="col-md-2">

                </div>
            </div>
```

Template:

```
<template class="section-template">
<!--need to change this name-->
<section id="input" class="wrapper style1 fullscreen intro">
    <div>
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputKi" class="col-sm-3 control-label">|Ki|</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="inputKi">
                </div>
                <label for="inputKi" class="col-sm-1 control-label">A</label>
            </div>
        </form>

        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputKf" class="col-sm-3 control-label">|Kf|</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="inputKf">
                </div>
                <label for="inputKf" class="col-sm-1 control-label">A</label>
            </div>
        </form>

        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputE" class="col-sm-3 control-label">E</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="inputE">
                </div>
                <label for="inputE" class="col-sm-1 control-label">meV</label>
            </div>
        </form>

        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputQ" class="col-sm-3 control-label">|Q|</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class=" input-sm form-control" id="inputQ">
                </div>
                <label for="inputE" class="col-sm-1 control-label">A</label>

            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</section>
</template>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Does your well have a fixed height? If so, try changing it to 100%

Comment: I tried changing the height but that doesn't work. I am able to substitute the template for a <h1> or <p> and the well adapts itself. The problem occurs when I try to use the template

Comment: which bootstrap version?